# In StrongLoop: Putting a strict array (a schema) in a model property

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopbackjs

I would like to create a model in StrongLoop
that will look like the following schema:

```
Item =
{
  "Name": {
    "en": "",
    "ru": "",
    "fr": ""
  },
  "Price": 0,
  "id": 0
}
```

How do i put a strict schema inside a property ("Name")?
Can i do it by editing the item.json file, or maybe from slc (command line)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can edit json and add stroct:true as shown here 
http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Model+JSON+file

or add {strict: true} set it in the model

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Creating+static+models

hth